# Call to undefined method codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

where i'm doing mistake? I tried to solve it, but nothing. I did all right, is the first time I have this error.

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Team_model::exist_team() in C:\wamp\www\example\application\libraries\teams.php on line 28
```

This is my library:

```
class Teams { // My class

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->ci->load->model('team_model');
    }


    function exist_team($team_id) { // this function give me that error

        if ($query_get_info = $this->ci->team_model->exist_team($id_team)) { // line with error
            return $query_get_info[0];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my model

```
class Team_model extends CI_Model {

    function exist_team($id_team) { // function exixst team in library
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('teams');
        $this->db->where('url',$id_team);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $query->result();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having same function name exist_team in library and controller is an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run this on a clean CI install without errors. Here's what I would check:

1. Make sure you're file names for both the model and library are capitalized. (Team_model.php & Teams.php).
   **Note -- [Codeigniter Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) state that only the Library names must be capitalized, but using the current version on GitHub, the load fails unless both files were capitalized.*
2. Declare the CI variable outside the constructor scope. This shouldn't be an issue, but it's worth exploring.

   ```
   class Teams { 
     private $_ci;

     function __construct()
     {
       $this->_ci =& get_instance();
       $this->_ci->load->model('team_model');
     }
   }
   ```

Unrelated, but an error: You use `$team_id` then `$id_team`.

```
function exist_team($team_id) {

if ($query_get_info = $this->ci->team_model->exist_team($id_team)) {
```

Comment: First, thank you very much for your time, I solve creating another model with another name. I don't know why but with that name it doesn't work. Cheese

Answer (score 1):

Check for spelling mistakes of Models name, if there is any spelling mistakes or distinct name from original model show error of Undefined Method.